# Ajax data doesn't make it to $_POST array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but none of the other answer to the other questions have helped me solve my problem.

I am writing a user login procedure that uses an `.ajax()` call to my `login.php` file to the log the user in. However, after several hours of debugging, I seem to have found out that the problem is that the `data: {user: username, pass: password}`line in my ajax call does not seem to send the data to my `$_POST` array in `login.php`. In fact, it won't even echo out my `if` statement in `login.php`. I know this problem sounds similar to others, but I have literally tried everything on this site that's related to the topic with no luck whatsoever.

Here's `login_form.php`. It contains the `.ajax()` code at the bottom:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom-style.css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login_container">
            <img src="img/sflogo.gif" alt="Sutton Ferneries" id="sflogo_login">
            <p id="add_err">We're sorry, we weren't able to find that username/password.</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            <p id="learn_login">Want to know the benefits of having an online account with us? <a href="#">Learn More.</a></p>
            <button id="login_btn">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
        $("#login_btn").on("click", function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = document.getElementById("password");
            password = password.value;

            $.ajax({
                url: "login.php",
                data: { user: username, pass: password },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#add_err").css('display', 'block', 'important');
                    $("#add_err").html("Loading...");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                document.write(data);
                    if (data == 'true') {
                        $("#login_container").html(data);
                        //closeLightbox();
                        window.location = "index.php";
                    } else {
                        $("#add_err").css('display', 'block', 'important');
                        $("#add_err").html("Wrong username or password.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</html>
```

And here's `login.php`:

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: application/json, true");

    if (!isset($_POST)) {
        echo 'Post is null';
    } else {
        echo 'Everything seems to be okay.';
    }

    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

?>
```

Comment: `dataType: "json",` - you are expecting/trying to send `json` type and  data but echoing text/html from server. please try something like `echo json_encode('Post is null');`

Comment: I just gave this a whirl, too, with no luck. It's not sending any data to the `success:` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
dataType: "json",
```

and

```
header("Content-Type: application/json, true");
```

and you will get result if you don't want to remove return back a json result and decode in success part and show them

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. Man, do I feel relieved. Thank you SO!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfect try to print the data

```
    echo   $username = $_POST['user'];

    echo $password = $_POST['pass'];
```

Comment: Just tried this and still no luck. I'm not sure what exactly what is happening, because I'm getting up to my `beforeSend:` call, but it never seems to call `success:`. Good to know it's working for you though, I'm going to keep playing around to see if it's something else in my code.

Comment: Remove all code add above two line only in login.php file

Answer (score 0):

You are using json in ajax. So the output should be something like this.

```
$output['msg'] = 'Here is your return';

echo json_encode($output);
```

Try this in login.php

In js you will get return as

```
alert(data.msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the Jquery min file in your code :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and why you are getting username through jquery method and password through javascript method..?? get it like this :

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
```

I've just made the above changes and everything worked fine..!!